# How to view the logs in a specific time range in openshift terminal

Tags: logging, openshift

Tried **head | tail** . But any specific way to query with time range

Answer (score 1):

No, that is unfortunately not possible, as `oc logs` does not know what timestamp format your logs are in. `oc logs` just returns plain text.

As a workaround, you could try to use `grep` like so (to filter anything between 10:00:00 and 10:09:59):

```
oc logs PODNAME | grep -e '10:0'
```